# Why does pressing the left command key sometimes trigger a window from Virtualbox

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu under virtualbox under OS X IN MacBook Pro.

A while ago, I asked a question about how to switch between windows in the guest Ubuntu by keystrokes, and the reply at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/241981/12994 suggested to press the left command key once before pressing alt-tab.

It sometimes works, but sometimes immediately following pressing the left command key, Virtualbox will pop up a window saying:

> You have clicked the mouse inside the Virtual Machine display or
>   pressed the host key. This will cause the Virtual Machine to capture
>   the host mouse pointer (only if the mouse pointer integration is not
>   currently supported by the guest OS) and the keyboard, which will make
>   them unavailable to other applications running on your host machine.
>   You can press the host key at any time to uncapture the keyboard and
>   mouse (if it is captured) and return them to normal operation. The
>   currently assigned host key is shown on the status bar at the bottom
>   of the Virtual Machine window, next to the ￼ icon. This icon, together
>   with the mouse icon placed nearby, indicate the current keyboard and
>   mouse capture state. The host key is currently defined as Left ⌘.

and asks me whether to choose cancel or capture.

Why does it sometimes work and sometimes brings out the interrupting Virtualbox window? How shall I switch between windows in the guest Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your mouse and keyboard is captured by the VM instance.

When you mouse is captured in the VM window, pressing the Left <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> will bring up the window you described.  When it's not captured, it won't.

If you want to avoid this problem, instal the Guest Additions.

Comment: Thanks I think I have installed the guest additions already. I am confused why sometimes pressing left-command key will bring out the virtualbox window and sometimes don't, and how I can make it work always.

Comment: It depends on if the mouse and/or keyboard is captured.  If it's not captured, it won't bring up the window.  If you have GA installed, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Yes, I think I should click Capture, and then I don't need to click the left command key any more as long as I  stay inside the guest Ubuntu.